# Showing that $||x||_p$ is continuous as a function of $p$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, means

I want to know if there is any mistake in my proof. Please bear with me the proof is a bit long a not very pretty. This seems very simple but I cannot think of a better way to prove it.

> Let $||\cdot||_p:\Bbb R^n\to \Bbb R$ be defined, for $p\ne 0$, by
>   $$
> ||(x_1,\dots,x_n)||_p:=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p\right)^{1/p},
> $$
>   I'll try to show that, for a fixed $x\in\Bbb R^n$, $M(p):=||x||_p$ is continuous on $\Bbb R\backslash \{0\}$.

Let $f:(0,\infty)\times\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ be defined by
$$
f(x,y):=x^y.
$$
Since
$
x^y=e^{y \ln x}
$,
so $$f=\exp\circ\ t\circ g$$ where $t(x,y)= yx$ and $g(x,y)=(\ln x,y)$. Since each of these $3$ functions is continuous, $f$ is continuous.

Let $h:\Bbb R\backslash\{0\}\to\Bbb R\times (\Bbb R\backslash\{0\})$ be defined as
$$
h(r):=\left( \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^r,1/r \right).
$$
We can see that $h$ is continuous also.

Since $M=f\circ h$, $M$ is continuous. QED

**Note**: I frequently make use of that fact that a function is continuous iff each of its component is continuous. Also, the trivial case where $x_1=\dots=x_n=0$ is not mentioned (I was too lazy to define $0^0$).

**PS.** If any of you have a shorter proof, I would be more than happy to look at it.

Comment: Your proof is incorrect: it does not make sense to compose $f$ with $h$ because the domain of $f$ is not contained in the codomain of $h$.

Comment: @Crostul So I should change $f:(0,\infty)\times\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$ to $f:(0,\infty)\times(\Bbb R\backslash\{0\})\to \Bbb R$, right?

Comment: Ok, now I have read better. Your proof is fine, you only need to redefine the codomain of $h$ as $(0, \infty) \times ( \Bbb{R} \setminus \{ 0 \} )$, and you are done.